# Freezing issue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I own a Dell Vostro 3500 with an Intel i5 CPU, 8GB DDR3 memory, NVIDIA GeForce GT 310M GPU and a 500GB SSD.
I recently installed Linux ubuntu - but ever since, I've been having problems.
I love ubuntu, but when I put my password and stuff, after login, it shows purple login screen, but can't see anything except my cursor that I can move around, m desktop fails to show up and program problem error comes up. I have researched all I can before coming here. I tried installing and reinstalling ubuntu and GPU drivers, unity, etc. Please, I need help as I'm a freelance IT specialist(Developer), and I need to get back to work.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using ubuntu 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I am using 64 bit package

Comment: goto the link below I put in my answer, and download the correct linux 64 bit driver!  That should correct your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a graphics driver issue to me.

If you can log in, open terminal.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
```

If you need to, start in safe mode, then follow the above instructions.

You can also download the correct driver here:

http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Here is the direct link for the driver you need:

http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/79413

You can also try 'additional drivers' from within ubuntu.

Comment: I've done that before though.

Comment: You have done which?

Comment: I've installed the same driver.

Comment: Have you tried the 32bit version of Ubuntu?

Comment: No, but won't that give me poor performance?

Comment: No, the only difference between 32bit and 64bit is the amount of memory that can be addressed.

Comment: Okay, which means I have to use another 1 GB of data bundles :(

Comment: Do you have somewhere to save the 32bit version?  Its really not a big deal...GOOD LUCK!  Let me know if 32bit helps at all!